# Prevent insertion of 'l' into editor when using Win+L

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-key

When locking my computer with the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> key, the char `l` is inserted into the text of any editor I'm using (I've experienced this with NetBeans, Notepad++ and PHPStorm). It's annoying to have this char inserted and break code.

Can I have the char prevented from being inserted? I typically hit  <kbd>Windows</kbd> first and then <kbd>L</kbd>, so it shouldn't be inserting the `l` key.

If I'm in a bash console, this sends a command that displays all the known hosts (from `/etc/hosts` I presume) and then `sl` which I then have to erase on the command line as well. Preventing this as well would be great.

I do know that I could do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> and achieve the same result, but to me, that's skirting the issue.

---

**Update**: This has something to do with my environment. I run Windows 7 host with all the above apps in a Fedora 21 VirtualBox. The problem only occurs in that environment (it does not occur in the Windows side). It occurs on a co-workers similar environment, which rules out hardware or something unique about my computer.

Comment: Which OS are you using? I just tried this on W10 with Notepad and NP++ also Windows 7 and Notepad. Neither on W7 or W10 did I get an L character.

Comment: I am unable to duplicate this. Do you have some type of key mapping or Autohotkey running? Does it only happen if the editor window is active? What if it is minimized? Does it happen with both Windows keys or only one?

Comment: Which OS are you using? I just tried this on W10 with Notepad and NP++ also Windows 7 and Notepad. Neither on W7 or W10 did I get an L character.

Comment: The window does need to be active / focus. This happens only in Fedora 21 running under a VirtualBox with Windows 7 host.

Comment: No special key mappings or autohotkey running. Both Windows keys.

Comment: This does not happen for me unless I am sloppy and let go of windows before I let go of L, and then only once in the ten times I've tried.

Comment: @FrankThomas I see the `l` char inserted into the editor before Windows locks. My finger is most definitely already on and remaining on the Windows key.

Comment: perhaps try another keyboard? this is clearly not how things are supposed to be. BASH? so you have Cygwin installed? that may have somthing to do with it.

Comment: It's definitely not my keyboard. A co-worker with the same environment has this occur as well. I checked all the shortcuts in Fedora and there is nothing mapped to Meta+L

Comment: Ahh, OK, I am able to reproduce it in a VBox instance of Mint, but only when an app in the VM has focus, and even then it only happened once in several attempts. The issue seems to be with VBox and the way it handles input being incompabitable with the way windows implements global hot keys. I think its safe to try to report it as a VBox bug.

Comment: I was on VBox 5.0.0. I upgraded to 5.0.10 and the problem still occurs. Created ticket: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14914

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VM machine didn't know what <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> was, so it would just insert the `l` char. Mapping `Meta+L` in the VM (Fedora) to no action prevents it from inserting the `l` char.

To do this in Fedora:

1. Open `Custom Shortcuts` from the menu. Click Edit > New > Global Shortcut > Send Keyboard Input.
2. Name the action (I choose "Ignore WinL")
3. In the `Trigger` tab, set the shortcut (this locked my computer as well).
4. Click OK.

It should now work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, running Virtualbox 5.1.24 on a Windows 7 host and Linux Arch client:

Virtual Box, deactivating:

File > Preferences > Input > Auto-capture keyboard (deactivate)

Now after locking with <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> whether you are on the client or host site, the former inserting of an `l` char is gone.